# Jenkins Dockerfile build : [91mstandard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Tags: python, linux, git, docker, jenkins

I have been trying to create a basic ci/cd pipeline for a python project on a raspberry pi 3. I am using Jenkins to build a Docker image and push it to my Dockerhub repo but I am getting an error during the Jenkins build:

`[91mstandard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"`

My Dockerfile is as follows

```
FROM arm32v7/python:3.7-slim-buster

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]
```

The problem occurs at the **RUN pip install** command so I thought that maybe the Jenkins worker couldn't access the file. So I added an extra command to change permissions:

```
FROM arm32v7/python:3.7-slim-buster

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]
```

The Jenkins build fails with the same error on the **chmod** command and it doesn't seem to be able to run any /bin scripts at all since all the /bin/sh commands fail. I thought maybe it was because Jenkins cannot apply certain commands because I specified the build in armv732? I am currently running Jenkins on the localhost of my machine running Ubuntu.
I am very new to both Jenkins and Docker so I'm not familiar with the specifics of how the systems work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Jenkins logs from the build:

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jenkins-test-docker
using credential 719f731b-6c8d-4712-aa71-d9c221c23a9c
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/CoogyEoin/ev_mqtt_monitor.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/CoogyEoin/ev_mqtt_monitor.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress -- https://github.com/CoogyEoin/ev_mqtt_monitor.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/testBranch^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/testBranch^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision b4d0ed413636fd076e5fae1518062f0ae479fea7 (refs/remotes/origin/testBranch)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f b4d0ed413636fd076e5fae1518062f0ae479fea7 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Seeing if chmod works"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 7be754300f5003e54139b34a8f3dff7eecc4f5bf # timeout=10
[jenkins-test-docker] $ docker build -t coogy/ev_mqtt_monitor_test --pull=true /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jenkins-test-docker
Sending build context to Docker daemon  216.1kB

Step 1/7 : FROM arm32v7/python:3.7-slim-buster
3.7-slim-buster: Pulling from arm32v7/python
Digest: sha256:0b115cbcf0c0a8164b2e486458af66418c78899a375750b9469c609c82c2cf36
Status: Image is up to date for arm32v7/python:3.7-slim-buster
 ---> 9a0c8b2b71f6
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6f702979c25d
Step 3/7 : RUN chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx requirements.txt
 ---> Running in c6a005a76880
[91mstandard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: That error means the CPU architecture is wrong. Is Jenkins using the PI as a build slave or some other machine?

Comment: Also, the Pi3 uses ARM Cortex-A53 which is ARMv8, not v7.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. It's not using the pi as a build slave it's just running off my Ubuntu machine. I presume it's not possible to build an ARM Dockerfile off an x_86 machines? I wasn't aware of this I'll try build the image on my pi and see if that works.
As for the CPU architecture I'm glad you pointed that out I actually didn't know that. Thank you for your advice if it works I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting indicates that the binary is build for a CPU architecture other than the one you are using as a build slave in Jenkins.
Most commands in a Dockerfile are executed inside a container based on the image specified in the Dockerfile, hence the architectures have to match.